# Resizing Annotation shapes

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create annotations in high charts and resizing the shapes on clicking inside a shape. I have created a js fiddle.

Run the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1e1jnv7w/

```
HTML:
<h3>Add annotation via simple form</h3>
<div style="width: 1054px; float: left;">
  <div id="container" style="float: left; height: 342px; width: 800px">
</div>

JAVASCRIPT:
$(function() {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
      borderRadius: 0,
      renderTo: 'container',
      backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
      //zoomType: 'x',
      events: {
        load: chartLoad
      }
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        'fontSize': '1em'
      },
      useHTML: true,
      x: -27,
      y: 8,
      text: '<span class="chart-title"> Drag and drop on a chart to add annotation  <span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
    },
    annotationsOptions: {
      enabledButtons: false
    },
    annotations: [{
      title: {
        text: '<span style="">drag me anywhere <br> dblclick to remove</span>',
        style: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      },
      anchorX: "left",
      anchorY: "top",
      allowDragX: true,
      allowDragY: true,
      x: 515,
      y: 55
    }, {
      title: 'drag me <br> horizontaly',
      anchorX: "left",
      anchorY: "top",
      allowDragY: false,
      allowDragX: true,
      xValue: 3,
      yValue: 10,
      shape: {
        type: 'path',
        params: {
          d: ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 110, 0],
          stroke: '#c55'
        }
      }
    }, {
      title: 'on point <br> drag&drop <br> disabled',
      linkedTo: 'high',
      anchorX: "middle",
      anchorY: "middle",
      allowDragY: false,
      allowDragX: false,
      shape: {
        type: 'circle',
        params: {
          r: 40,
          stroke: '#c55'
        }
      }
    }, {
      x: 100,
      y: 200,
      title: 'drag me <br> verticaly',
      anchorX: "left",
      anchorY: "top",
      allowDragY: true,
      allowDragX: false,
      shape: {
        type: 'rect',
        params: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 55,
          height: 40
        }
      }
    }],
    series: [{
      data: [13, 4, 5, {
          y: 1,
          id: 'high'
        },
        2, 14, 3, 2, 11, 6
      ]
    }]
  };

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options, function(chart) {

    var container = chart.container,
      offsetX = chart.plotLeft - container.offsetLeft,
      offsetY = chart.plotTop - container.offsetTop;
    Highcharts.addEvent(container, 'mousedown', function(e) {
      var isInside = chart.isInsidePlot(e.clientX - offsetX, e.pageY - offsetY);
    });
  });

  function chartLoad() {
    var chart = this,
      container = chart.container,
      annotations = chart.annotations.allItems,
      annotation,
      clickX,
      clickY;

    function getParams(e) {

      function getRadius(e) {

        var x = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft,
          y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop,
          dx = Math.abs(x - clickX),
          dy = Math.abs(y - clickY);
        return parseInt(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy), 10);
      }

      function getPath(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft,
          y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop,
          dx = x - clickX,
          dy = y - clickY;

        return ["M", 0, 0, 'L', parseInt(dx, 10), parseInt(dy, 10)];
      }

      function getWidth(e) {
        var x = e.clientX - container.offsetLeft,
          dx = Math.abs(x - clickX);

        return parseInt(dx, 10) + 1;
      }

      function getHeight(e) {
        var y = e.pageY - container.offsetTop,
          dy = Math.abs(y - clickY);

        return parseInt(dy, 10) + 1;
      }

      if (!annotation.options.shape) return;

      var shape = annotation.options.shape.params;
      var newShape = {};
      if (shape.r) {

        newShape.r = getRadius(e);
      }
      if (shape.d) {
        newShape.d = getPath(e);
      }
      if (shape.width) {
        newShape.width = getWidth(e);
      }
      if (shape.height) {
        newShape.height = getHeight(e);
      }
      return newShape;
    }


    function drag(e) {
       //  alert("Hii");
      var shape = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
        stroke = $("#stroke").val(),
        strokeWidth = $("#strokeWidth").val(),
        title = $("#title").val(),
        fill = $("#fill").val(),
        shapeOpt = null,
        x = null,
        y = null,
        width = null,
        height = null,
        radius = 20;


      clickX = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
      clickY = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;


      if (!chart.isInsidePlot(clickX - chart.plotLeft, clickY - chart.plotTop)) {
        return;
      }


      if (shape == 'rect') {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        width = 1;
        height = 1;
        radius = 1;
      }
      if (shape !== 'text') {
        shapeOpt = {
          type: shape,
          params: {
            r: shape == 'circle' ? 1 : 0,
            d: shape == 'path' ? ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 1, 1] : null,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: width,
            height: height
          }
        };
        title = null;
        Highcharts.addEvent(document, 'mousemove', step);
      }
      chart.addAnnotation({
        x: clickX,
        y: clickY,
        allowDragX: true,
        allowDragY: true,
        anchorX: 'left',
        anchorY: 'top',
        title: title,
        shape: shapeOpt
      });

      annotation = annotations[annotations.length - 1];

    }

    function step(e) {
      // use renderer api for better performance
      annotation.shape.attr(getParams(e));
    }

    function drop(e) {

      Highcharts.removeEvent(document, 'mousemove', step);

      // store annotation details
      if (annotation) {
        annotation.update({
          shape: {
            params: getParams(e)
          }
        });
      }
      annotation = null;
    }
  function sal(e)
  {

     // Highcharts.removeEvent(container, 'dblclick', step);
    var each = Highcharts.each;

     each(chart.annotations.allItems, function (item, i) {
        if (item.selectionMarker) {
          shape = item.shape.element.localName;
        }
    });

     // var shape = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
      var shapeOpt = null,
        x = null,
        y = null,
        width = null,
        height = null,
        radius = null;


      clickX = e.pageX - container.offsetLeft;
      clickY = e.pageY - container.offsetTop;


      if (!chart.isInsidePlot(clickX - chart.plotLeft, clickY - chart.plotTop)) {
        return;
      }

      if (shape == 'rect') {
        x = clickX;
        y = clickY;
        width = 1;
        height = 1;
        radius = 1;
      }
      if (shape !== 'text') {
        shapeOpt = {
          type: shape,
          params: {
            r: shape == 'circle' ? 1 : 0,
            d: shape == 'path' ? ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 1, 1] : null,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: width,
            height: height
          }
        };
        title = null;
        Highcharts.addEvent(document, 'mousemove', step);
      }


      annotation = annotations[annotations.length - 1];
  }

  //  Highcharts.addEvent(container, 'mousedown', drag);
    Highcharts.addEvent(document, 'mouseup', drop);
     Highcharts.addEvent(container, 'dblclick', sal);

    $('#ann1size').click(function() {
      var ann = annotations[annotations.length - 1];
      ann.update({
        shape: {
          params: {
            r: 200
          }
        }
      })
    });
  }
});
```

1. double click on square shape, you can resize it now.
2. double click on circle shape, its still resizing square shape.

Can you please let me know how to fix this issue that no matter which shape is double clicked, square is getting resized.

Answer (score 0):

I think that right now you have problem with getting right annotation in your chart. You are getting always the same rect shape because you are using fixed:

```
      annotation = annotations[annotations.length - 1];
```

Instead this line, you can set your annotation object inside Highcharts.each:

```
      var each = Highcharts.each;
  each(chart.annotations.allItems, function(item, i) {
    if (item.selectionMarker) {
      annotation = item;
      shape = item.shape.element.localName;
    }
  });
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/1e1jnv7w/3/

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way to hide the dotted rectangular box which is seen during resizing any shape.

Comment: Hi, Yes, this is possible by changing stroke-width of your item.selectionMarker. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/1e1jnv7w/15/